# Consuming a web service over a HTTPS connection

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am trying to build a web service consumer in Java using Apache CXF. I've managed to generate the required classes using the **WSDLToJava** tool. After that, I've made some test requests using a local web service over HTTP and they worked.

Since everything was in order, I generated classes for the remote web service endpoint which uses HTTPS for communication. When consuming a service, I need to create a new instance of the Service class generated and also a port (proxy for the web methods available).

Here are my two problems with this classes:

1. The service class always takes ~20s to instantiate which didn't happened for the local web service
2. When trying to retrieve the port (proxy) class from the service, it doesn't time out, but hangs, while the processor is 70% used and eventually the JVM runs out of memory.

Below are the two lines of code I've talked about. I've even used the utility to generate a test class and the result is the same.

`TestService ss = new TestService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
 TestSoap port = ss.getTestSoap();`

Do you have any ideas why this behaviour appears?

Comment: profiling should be a good start here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem. I will tell you, since maybe somebody may find this useful.

I made some tests and it seemed that after some time, the test method started to hang in `java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1()`

The problem appeared because I was running an Ant target that generated the classes using WSDL2Java and the JAVA_HOME variable pointed to Java 8. The testing was made in IDEA which used Java 7. I switched IDEA to use Java 8 ant now they work correctly.

After further investigation I've found the real problem. The PermGen was filling with to many classes (~7.5k) when loading the proxy class. Since Java 8 doesn't have any PermGen, the problem doesn't appear. I've added the JVM flags `-XX:PermSize` and `-XX:MaxPermSize` and increased the size of it for Java 7.